# how to remove the results of the previous image on tcanvas

Tags: delphi, canvas

its this code

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
SpeedButton1.Tag := SpeedButton1.Tag + 1;
if SpeedButton1.Tag = 4 then
SpeedButton1.Tag := 0;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with Image1.Canvas do
begin
Brush.Style := BSSolid;
Pen.Color := $0000FF;
Pen.Style := PSSolid;
Pen.Width := 5;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
case SpeedButton1.Tag of
0 :
Ellipse(Image1.Width - 45, 4, Image1.Width - 35, 14);
1 :
Ellipse(Image1.Width - 45, 32, Image1.Width - 35, 42);
2 :
Ellipse(Image1.Width - 115, 4, Image1.Width - 125, 14);
3 :
Ellipse(Image1.Width - 115, 32, Image1.Width - 125, 42);
end;
SpeedButton1.Caption := 'Pos : '+IntToStr(SpeedButton1.Tag);
end;
Image1.Invalidate;
{ Image1.Canvas.Refresh;
Image1.Repaint;
Image1.Refresh;
}
end;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
DoubleBuffered := true;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with Image1.Canvas do
begin
Brush.Style := BSClear;
Pen.Color := $000000;
Pen.Style := PSSolid;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pen.Width := 5;
MoveTo(Image1.Width - 2, 6);
LineTo(Image1.Width - 2, 40);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pen.Width := 2;
MoveTo(Image1.Width - 80, 6);
LineTo(Image1.Width - 80, 40);
MoveTo(Image1.Width - 160, 6);
LineTo(Image1.Width - 160, 40);
MoveTo(Image1.Width - 240, 6);
LineTo(Image1.Width - 240, 40);
MoveTo(Image1.Width - 320, 6);
LineTo(Image1.Width - 320, 40);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pen.Width := 1;
MoveTo(0, 8);
LineTo(Image1.Width, 8);
MoveTo(0, 38);
LineTo(Image1.Width, 38);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brush.Style := BSSolid;
Pen.Color := $0000FF;
Pen.Style := PSSolid;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pen.Width := 5;
Ellipse(Image1.Width - 45, 4, Image1.Width - 35, 14);
end;
Image1.Invalidate;
end;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: i mean : how to remove the chord [C] in the picture, when the button is pressed on the chord [D] canvas only display images chord [D].

sorry about my English.

Comment: You should probably be using a TPaintBox here. You don't want a persistent image. TImage is designed for static images.

Comment: I never used TPaintBox but I can not update the ellipse on canvas outside OnPaint procedure on TPaintBox, e.g: I update new ellipse using the button can not arise. please give me a simple example of what you mean. thank you

Comment: There are plenty of examples of using `TPaintBox`. I'm sure Embarcadero provide some. Rather than me searching for them and pointing you at them, I'm sure that you'll be able to find them with a web search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FillRect to fill a rectangular region using the current brush. The region is filled including the top and left sides of the rectangle, but excluding the bottom and right edges.

```
begin
  Image1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWtite;
  Image1.Canvas.FillRect(Image1.Canvas.ClipRect);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `TImage` control holds a simple bitmap. It does not hold layers. This means that you cannot remove the chord and leave the string lines. The string lines were already drawn over and need to be re-drawn.

Since you need to re-draw the string lines it seems to me that it will be simplest to re-draw the entire canvas. I would say that `TImage` is the wrong control for this task. It is suited for static images.

For a dynamic image like this, a `TPaintBox` is a better choice. You supply an `OnPaint` event handler. You must also remember the state that needs to be drawn. This state will contain the details of the chord and its fingering. When you need to re-draw, update this state and call `Invalidate` the paint box. This will force a paint cycle which will call your `OnPaint` handler.